# Toggling in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I just learned how to include a toggle filter in Tableau, so I can move from one worksheet to another on my dashboard.

My dashboard has two charts (each to be broken down by day and month--hence the toggle), and I want to be able to switch between the day and month.

I was wondering if it is possible to have one toggle change both charts simultaneously, and if so, how would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Right click the Filter pill and use the `apply to worksheets` menu to tell the filter to work on both sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try right clicking the `Filter` and subsequently select `Apply to Worksheets`. This will successfully tell the filter to ensure that the toggle works on both sheets. Hope this helps!